# Distributed system clock

Tags: distributed, clock

I was reading the following about vector clocks:
http://book.mixu.net/distsys/time.html

I must be missing something. Due to network latency is there always an "ack/nack"? If node B is updating node C and node C message that is updating node B is in transit, there must be an acknowledgment occurring as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, ack/nack is from a different layer than vector clocks. You use ack/nack to acknowledge that a package was correctly transmitted / received via the transportation layer (TCP for instance).

Vector clocks are in the application layer. They ensure that you can order messages by the [happened before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) logic. This is relevant for instance, for different scenarios when you store and replicate/synchronise data.

Usually in distributed algorithms you send (and therefore also receive) messages asynchronously, to divide work or updating results, without expecting any direct answer. Such an asynchronous communication reduces the network overhead and increases the throughput as well as speed at which the nodes can communicate.

Imagine two processes (people) working on the same dataset (document) and updating each other.
Processes A and B start both from 0, A's vector clock is (0,0) and B's as well (0,0) - each entry is for (A, B)

1. A makes a change and sends an update to B

   - A: (1, 0); B: (0, 0)
2. B makes a change and sends an update to A

   - A: (1, 0); B: (0, 1)
3. A makes another change and sends an update to B

   - A: (2, 0); B: (0, 1)
4. A receives B's update and sees on the vector clock (0, 1)

   - A now knows that B didn't apply any of A's updates to the document yet and know which data need to be merged
   - A: (2, 1); B: (0, 1)
5. B receives A's both messages after each other and needs to perform a similar merge

   - A: (2, 1); B: (2, 1)

Now if A needed to wait with the changes until B sends a confirmation, before sending another message, it would have wasted a lot of time. And in the end there would have been anyway a conflict since they sent the updates concurrently and would have either needed to merge them, or at least one process would have needed to withdraw it's changes.